# Tools to Find & Fix C# coding standards

Tags: c#, ndepend

I am using a tool called NDEPEND to scan my C# solution to find the coding issues. The tool  nicely list down the coding violations according to the category. My question is, will this tool give auto suggestion on the change that should be done to the listed coding issues? I cannot find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the list of [default NDepend rules](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html), you'll see they all come with two comment sections:  `<Description>` and `<HowToFix>`. The `<HowToFix>` section contains suggestions about how to fix the issues.

This feature came with [NDepend v6](http://www.ndepend.com/ndepend-v6#DefaultRules) released in June 2015, maybe you are using a former version?

For example it looks like:

```
// <Name>Base class should not use derivatives</Name>

warnif count > 0 
from baseClass in JustMyCode.Types
where baseClass.IsClass && baseClass.NbChildren > 0 // <-- for optimization!
let derivedClassesUsed = baseClass.DerivedTypes.UsedBy(baseClass)
where derivedClassesUsed.Count() > 0
select new { baseClass, derivedClassesUsed }

//<Description>
// In *Object-Oriented Programming*, the **open/closed principle** states:
// *software entities (components, classes, methods, etc.) should be open 
// for extension, but closed for modification*. 
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle
//
// Hence a base class should be designed properly to make it easy to derive from,
// this is *extension*. But creating a new derived class, or modifying an
// existing one, shouldn't provoke any *modification* in the base class.
// And if a base class is using some derivative classes somehow, there
// are good chances that such *modification* will be needed.
//
// Extending the base class is not anymore a simple operation,
// this is not good design.
//</Description>

//<HowToFix>
// Understand the need for using derivatives, 
// then imagine a new design, and then refactor.
//
// Typically an algorithm in the base class needs to access something 
// from derived classes. You can try to encapsulate this access behind 
// an abstract or a virtual method.
//
// If you see in the base class some conditions on *typeof(DerivedClass)*
// not only *urgent refactoring* is needed. Such condition can easily 
// be replaced through an abstract or a virtual method.
//
// Sometime you'll see a base class that creates instance of some derived classes.
// In such situation, certainly using the *factory method pattern* 
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern
// or the *abstract factory pattern* 
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern
// will improve the design. 
//</HowToFix>
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Yes I can find it in my version of NDEPEND as well. Actually I thought the NDEPEND will give suggestions/Hints just like in Resharper.